# How does Arrakis maintain a breathable atmosphere without vegetation?

Tags: dune

Arrakis (also known as "Dune") is an entirely desert planet that has had a sizable population of Fremen who have lived there for generations, in addition to numerous offworlders. Breathing of course converts oxygen to carbon dioxide, and plants are the primary way that carbon dioxide is converted back into oxygen. Yet vegetation is virtually absent on Arrakis.

**How is it that Arrakis maintains a breathable atmosphere without vegetation?**

<sub>Credit to the web video [Frank Herbert's Dune - The Dom Reviews](https://youtu.be/FdT99Q7zLzY) for raising this question.</sub>

Comment: It's not canon, so probably not worthy of an answer in itself, but _The Dune Encyclopedia_ attempted to answer this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrakis#The_Dune_Encyclopedia

Comment: @tobiasvl - I though of adding it in. There's a whole bunch about the oxygen cycle on Arrakis but it largely boils down to "the worms".

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Pardot Kynes, the Imperial Planetologist noticed that too.

> *“Water overshadows the other problems,” Kynes said. “This planet has
>   much oxygen without its usual concomitants—widespread plant life and
>   large sources of free carbon dioxide from such phenomena as volcanoes.
>   There are unusual chemical interchanges over large surface areas
>   here.”*
>
> <sub><sup>[Dune](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dune_(novel))</sup></sub>

And many visitors wondered where all the free oxygen comes from.

> *“The Arrakeen environment built itself into the evolutionary pattern
>   of native life forms,” his father said. “How strange that so few
>   people ever looked up from the spice long enough to wonder at the
>   near-ideal nitrogen-oxygen-CO2 balance being maintained here in the
>   absence of large areas of plant cover. The energy sphere of the planet
>   is there to see and understand—a relentless process, but a process
>   nonetheless. There is a gap in it? Then something occupies that gap.
>   Science is made up of so many things that appear obvious after they
>   are explained. I knew the little maker was there, deep in the sand,
>   long before I ever saw it.”*
>
> <sub><sup>[Dune](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dune_(novel))</sup></sub>

Without realising that it was coming from the same place as the spice, from the giant sandworms of Arrakis.

> *But his inner digestive “factory,” with its enormous concentrations of
>   aldehydes and acids, was a giant source of oxygen. A medium worm
>   (about 200 meters long) discharged into the atmosphere as much oxygen
>   as ten square kilometers of green-growing photosynthesis surface.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Dune](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dune_(novel))</sup></sub>

---

Additionally, there are *some* plants in the lower latitudes, where the air is (relatively) moistest.

> *“Are there any plants down there?” Paul asked.
>
>   “Some,” Kynes said. “This latitude’s life-zone has mostly what we call minor water stealers—adapted to raiding each other for moisture, gobbling up the trace-dew. Some parts of the desert teem with life. But all of it has learned how to survive under these rigors. If you get caught down there, you imitate that life or you die.”*
>
> <sub><sup>[Dune](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dune_(novel))</sup></sub>

Comment: I guess Kynes eventually found out where oxygen came from first hand.

Comment: @KimberlyW - There's nothing like an object lesson.

Comment: Isn't there also a scene where someone (Paul?) notices the oxygen-rich air near a sandworm? Maybe the sandcrawler scene in the beginning of book 1?

Comment: Ah, no, wait, I think it's the smell of *ozone* that is mentioned. (Which is of course a molecule composed of oxygen.)

Comment: @JörgWMittag TIL that ozone has an odour!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: The characteristic smell of old laser printers was caused by the high energies in the printing mechanism producing radical O1 some of which then fuses with O2 to O3. I think. Something like that. Anyway, it's ozone smell.

Comment: @JörgWMittag - And the smell before it rains.

Comment: @Valorum: … and after lightning. Come to think of it, there are quite a number of ozone sources both natural and technological.

Comment: It's good handwaving, but it's all nonsense. The whole ecosystem lacks an energy source which is what green plants provide capturing solar energy as chemical energy.

Comment: @MarkOlson - They have plants

Comment: @MarkOlson We have a question on the (rather dubious) biological energy cycle of Arrakis: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/182222/116908

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd throw in another (non-canonical) explanation for a planet supporting a breathable atmosphere with little vegetation without resorting to giant worms. Check out *The Life and Death of Planet Earth: How the New Science of Astrobiology Charts the Ultimate Fate of Our World* by Peter Ward and Donald Brownlee for more details.

It boils down to Dune being a planet with an ecosystem on its last legs due to its aging sun getting steadily brighter. Conceivably, Arrakis once supported a climate like the Earth. Assuming Arrakis's sun is a G-type star similar in size to our own sun (*not* Canopus as described in *Dune*, which is a giant star likely too young for life to have evolved on Arrakis), over billions of years its luminosity gradually increased as it evolved off of the main sequence. As temperatures rose on Arrakis's surface, weathering scrubbed more CO2 from Arrakis's atmosphere, maintaining a hospitable environment on the surface even as its sun grows brighter. However, at some point the CO2 buffer in Arrakis's atmosphere will be reduced to near zero levels, barely enough to support plants.

This would leave us with a hot desert planet with a breathable oxygen/nitrogen atmosphere, no or very little CO2, and few plants. How long free oxygen would remain in the atmosphere is a good question. If the surface is already completely oxidized and there are no volcanoes producing gases like hydrogen and methane which react strongly with oxygen, an oxygen atmosphere could be stable for millions of years. This scenario doesn't explain what happened to Dune's oceans, unless the planet had very little water to being with.

Comment: As noted above,  the situation on Arrakis had nothing to do with the actual climate, the star, or the amount of free water: the desertification was entirely due to the sandworms.